# Schrodinger semigroup and conservation laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider a sufficiently fast decaying and smooth function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx=0.
$$
Now consider the Schrodinger semigroup $e^{it\partial_x^2}$, that is, the operator such that $$
\mathcal{F}\big[e^{it\partial_x^2}f\big](\xi)=e^{-it\xi^2}\mathcal{F}[f](\xi).
$$
Is it true that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{it\partial_x^2}\big(f(x-t)\big)dx=0?
$$
I do believe that, if we put $f(x)$ instead of $f(x-t)$ in the last line it should be true  since (sufficiently fast decaying) solutions to the equation $$
i\partial_t u+\partial_x^2u=0
$$
conserve the average $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(t,x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(0,x)dx.
$$
So in that sense, I would like to do something like $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{it\partial_x^2}\big(f(x-t)\big)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-t)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx=0,
$$
but I'm not 100% sure if that is allowed given the time dependence in $f(x-t)$. Does anybody know how to prove or disprove the above claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote Fourier transform by $\hat{}$.
$$
\hat{f}(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=0
$$
Let $g_t(x)=f(x-t)$ and $h_t(x)=\left(e^{it\partial_x^2}g_t\right)(x)$.  You're looking for the value of
$$
\hat{h}(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x)dx=0
$$
Now
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{g_t}(\xi)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_t(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-t)e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x')e^{-i(x'+t)\xi}dx'\\
&=e^{-it\xi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x')e^{-ix'\xi}dx'=e^{-it\xi}\hat{f}(\xi)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\hat{h}(\xi)=e^{-it\xi^2}\hat{g_t}(\xi)=e^{-it\xi^2}e^{-it\xi}\hat{f}(\xi)=e^{-it(\xi^2+\xi)}\hat{f}(\xi)
$$
so
$$
\hat{h}(0)=e^{-it(0^2+0)}\hat{f}(0)=1\cdot 0=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's ok. For each fixed $t\in\mathbb R$, the operator $e^{it\partial_x^2}$ commutes with translations, as you can see via the PDE or via the Fourier transform, as you prefer. Therefore,
$$
e^{it\partial_x^2}(f(\cdot - t))(x)=(e^{it\partial_x^2}f)(x -t).$$
Integrating in $x$, changing variable to $y=x-t$ (no problem here, since $t$ is fixed), you are back to the case you know.